# Get object inside more than one object MYSQL JSON

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel, json-extract

How can I select array "1" inside the "flavor" object from **json** code in mysql

Attribute name: **settings**

```
{"without":{"usd":{"new":"5","old":"8"},"weight":"5"},"color":{"2","3"},"flavor":{"1","2"}}
```

And how can I get a number inside the "usd" object inside "new" knowing these objects are inside the first object and they are variable, perhaps ["without" or "long" or ......]

Attribute name: **settings**

```
{"without":{"usd":{"new":"5","old":"8"},"weight":"5"},"color":{"2","3"},"flavor":{["1","2"}}
{"long":{"usd":{"new":"2","old":"3"},"weight":"2"},"medium":{"usd":{"new":"3","old":"4"},"weight":"3"},"short":{"usd":{"new":"4","old":"5"},"weight":"4"}}
{"short":{"usd":{"new":"4","old":"5"},"weight":"2"},"color":{"1","2"}}
```

LIKE

```
without = 5
long = 2
short = 4
```

Comment: These are not *arrays*, but *objects* that are nested within the top object (json arrays are delimited by `[]`, and objects by `{}`). Objects keys have no particular order, so there is no notion of "first" key. This makes your requirement unclear.

Comment: @GMB I changed from an array to an object

Comment: OK. But there is no "first" object. JSON keys are unordered. What you are seeing is just a representation of the data, which is not guaranteed to be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebuilt the data format so that I could extract the required data

```
{"size":[{"id":1,"url":"without","weight":"5","price":{"usd":{"new":"5","old":"8"}}}],"color":[{"id":"2","url":"yellow"},{"id":"3","url":"green"}],"flavor":[{"id":"1","url":"berry"},{"id":"2","url":"strawberry"}]}
```

MYSQL

```
JSON_EXTRACT(details.settings, '$.color[*].url') LIKE '%yellow%'
```

Comment: Yes. Now you use JSON arrays, and the problem can be solved.